# Raspberry Pi 4B won't connect to 802.11ac WiFi

Tags: wifi, pi-4, ubuntu

802.11ac was supposed to be compatible with Pi 4, right?  I recently tried using 802.11ac only to maximize the WiFi performance, but as soon as I did that, the Pi disconnected I have & to enable 802.11n in order for the Pi to connect to that SSID.

When I used nmcli dev wifi connect  password  I get the error saying "secrets were required but not provided", even with the --ask option.

I have Ubuntu Server 20.04 on my Raspberry Pi 4B 2GB, which I'm using as my AirPlay receiver.

I tried using [Netplan based on this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1249858/558318) after reinstalling Ubuntu Server, but WiFi remained disconnected unless I reenable 802.11n.

Comment: The wifi chip may be potentially fried OR it may be a faulty chip James

Comment: Ubuntu Server does not use Network Manager (unless you installed a Desktop), so `nmcli` won't help. You should ask on  a Ubuntu site. Configuration using yaml should be independent of hardware (other than device names).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not the only one:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=268615

The problem appears to be an incorrect country code in `wpa_supplicant.conf`.  These are significant because of [different national restrictions on available channels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#5_GHz_or_5.9_GHz_(802.11a/h/j/n/ac/ax)) in the frequency range.

[Here's a list of 802.11 country codes.](https://www.arubanetworks.com/techdocs/InstantWenger_Mobile/Advanced/Content/Instant%20User%20Guide%20-%20volumes/Country_Codes_List.htm)

Ubuntu may not expose or intend you to edit `wpa_supplicant.conf` directly, but you should still be able to set the country code one way or another; see comments below.

Comment: AFAIK Ubuntu Server does not use wpa_supplicant although country code is probably the problem. It is possible to use wpa_supplicant with networkd-systemd but this differs from Raspbian setup.

Comment: I think it probably does (I do not think there are any options available besides https://iwd.wiki.kernel.org/), but it may not expose the configuration the same way because it is integrated differently (the config is derived from the netplan yaml stuff).

Comment: Hmm there is a (non-authoritative) note here about where to put the country code w/ netplan, in a Pi context: https://gist.github.com/Jiab77/76000284f8200da5019a232854421564 (search down for "country code").  It also mentions this is an issue there (the country code set incorrectly).